# Django: static image file should be stored in git repository when using AWS cloudfront and S3?

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I developed my `Django` project with `AWS cloudfront and S3`.

I wonder whether static image file(not media file) should be stored in git repository.

I think that if I run `collectstatic --settings="production.settings` all static files seems to be uploaded on my `S3`.

If so, I think that I don't need to store all static image files in git repository.

Am I right?

Comment: I can't understand the question. After deploying, your .py files will now be in the production server. Does this mean you should delete them from the repository?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides what are you talking about? Why do you say `.py` file? I just want to know about static image file

Comment: If the reasoning "they are in S3, so I don't need them in my repository" was correct for static files, then it would also be correct for .py files. Static files are a part of your program's source code. What if tomorrow you want to deploy on Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 1):

In general yes. You can remove them from repository, because you have uploaded static files to S3

but...

Consider following scenario. Accidentally you will call collectstatic with clear option. All the static files will be removed from S3. Then you have to upload static files again into repository. Do you want it?

Also there is another reason why it is convenient to keep static files. If you are using S3, then you can save some money and time uploading only changed files into the bucket. For that you can use, for instance, [collectfast](https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast). If you will delete files then collectfast won't be able to calculate md5 checksums and probably won't work at all.

Comment: "Then you have to upload static files again into repository, Do you want it?" => But if I run `collectstatic` even in my production server, all static images are 'automatically' uploaded in S3. I cannot control it.

Comment: @user3595632 I think I didn't get you correctly but if you will remove all the files from git and also from production server, then after collectstatic nothing will be uploaded to the s3.

Comment: Before deploying, I can run `collectstatic` in my local machine then all static files are uploaded in s3

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible. But still you have control. If u change any static file you can upload them again. It does not matter if you are doing it from development or production machine